# Why doesn't my masked object have a stroke from the object it's in?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

I have a group which has a stroke applied:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/YZ5lqqB.png]

And I want to mask part of an object to change the color on part of it. But when I mask the two objects, it stops applying the stroke to that object.

[image]

Is there any way to fix that or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your stroke isn't actually a stroke, but rather a second shape which is slightly larger - behind the path.

Clipping masks follow the path of the **topmost** object, and they then make *that* path **invisible**.

If you wanted an area "clipped" (cut off), you would put the object defining the *clipping area* - the area you want to **keep** on the top and then turn it into a clipping mask.

---

> In your scenario, I would suggest that you use an actual stroke for
>   everything (*it'll make things simpler later on*) and then you can
>   bring the brown box to the front in order to use it as the clipping
>   path.

---

If you really want to make this properly, I would suggest to merge the two shapes (the ear and the head) using the *Shape Builder Tool* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)

[image]

This would also make it that you didn't need clipping masks.

I made my piglet by creating a few circles and polygons (for filler), made one ear and reflected it to the other side, and then merged them all together with Shape Builder:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. The shape builder tool worked. I was just hoping there was a less destructive way, but at least it was easy.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of looks to me that when you apply the mask, the object and it's mask *leave the group* with the stroke applied.

You may be able to merely move the `<clip group>` back inside the `<Group>`.

Impossible to tell without seeing the layers panel *after* the mask is applied.

Comment: The screenshot he attached shows after the mask is applied.

Comment: @WELZ How can you tell? There's no `<clip group>` and the main layer *clearly* shows there's an Appearance panel stroke applied to the layer. You *guessed* as much as I did `:)` they are merely different *guesses*. I think the path used for the clipping mask in on another layer. so when the mask is applied, the object moves to *that* layer without the Appearance Panel stroke.

Comment: From the *result* - if you look at the layer preview (also the brown *triangle*) you can see that that's what it looked like after the mask is applied in the gif.

Comment: I still think you're *guessing* as much as I am `:)`.

Comment: I am too self *right*eous...  **:P**

Comment: `:)` *"... your stroke isn't actually a stroke..."* there's really no evidence of that fact. The meatball **is** filled so.... who knows `:)`

Comment: I don't know, it seemed very obvious to me that it's the clip group, there's the dropdown triangle, the preview of the layer (and the path) both show what it looked like *after* the mask was applied in the gif.

Comment: Triangle doesn't automatically mean **clip** group. It may just mean group.

Comment: We'll have to wait for OP to provide more insight.

Comment: The way I know it *isn't* a stroke is that stroked items **will** show up in the layers panel with a stroke ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk2Ir.png))

Comment: the screenshot is after the mask was applied